# PRAW Errors updating to new Python Distro

Tags: python, reddit, praw

So I am trying to create a bot that cross posts from a sub (r/pics) to (r/polpics) using a bit of code from u/GoldenSights.  I upgraded to a new python distro and I get a ton of errors, I don't even know where to begin.  Here is the code (formatting off, error lines bold):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tonyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-
packages\praw\subdump.py", line 84, in <module>
    r = praw.Reddit(USERAGENT)
  File "C:\Users\tonyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\praw\reddit.py", line 150, in __init__
    raise ClientException(required_message.format(attribute))
praw.exceptions.ClientException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' 
missing.
This setting can be provided in a praw.ini file, as a keyword argument to the `Reddit` class constructor, or as an environment variable.
```

This seems to be related to USERAGENT setting.  I don't think I have that configured right.

```
USERAGENT = ""
# This is a short description of what the bot does. For example 
"/u/GoldenSights' Newsletter bot"
SUBREDDIT = "pics"
# This is the sub or list of subs to scan for new posts.
# For a single sub, use "sub1".
# For multiple subs, use "sub1+sub2+sub3+...".
# For all use "all"
KEYWORDS = ["It looks like this post is about US Politics."]
# Any comment containing these words will be saved.
KEYDOMAINS = []
# If non-empty, linkposts must have these strings in their URL
```

This is the error line:

```
print('Logging in')
r = praw.Reddit(USERAGENT) <--here, this is error line 84
r.set_oauth_app_info(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, APP_URI)
r.refresh_access_information(APP_REFRESH)
```

Also in Reddit.py :

```
raise ClientException(required_message.format(attribute)) <--- error

praw.exceptions.ClientException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' 
missing.
This setting can be provided in a praw.ini file, as a keyword argument to 
the `Reddit` class constructor, or as an environment variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're going to want to have your API credentials stored externally in your [praw.ini file](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/prawini.html). This makes things a lot more secure, and looks like it might go some way to fixing your issue. Here's what a completed praw.ini file looks like, including the useragent, so try to replicate this.

```
[DEFAULT]
# A boolean to indicate whether or not to check for package updates.
check_for_updates=True

# Object to kind mappings
comment_kind=t1
message_kind=t4
redditor_kind=t2
submission_kind=t3
subreddit_kind=t5

# The URL prefix for OAuth-related requests.
oauth_url=https://oauth.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for regular requests.
reddit_url=https://www.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for short URLs.
short_url=https://redd.it

[appname]
 client_id=IE*******T14_w
client_secret=SW***********************CLY
password=******************
username=appname
user_agent=web:appname:1.0.0 (by /u/username)
```

Let me know how things go after you sort this out.